# When does a new proposal/site get promoted?

Tags: support, area-51, advertising, sidebar

From time to time we see sidebar advertisements promoting new Area51 proposals or new sites like

[image: example ad]

On what criteria are those ads chosen? Are those hand-picked, is there an algorithm? Can I do something to get a new site* in the sidebar?

<sub>* Like the new site [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) which has its own add now</sub>

Comment: Given the nature of SR, do we really want to promote it that much until there is sufficient community moderation?

Comment: The more users joining the site, the faster we will se if it works. And if the current moderators need help, additionals will be elected.